# DJI Desktop application

Tags: dji-sdk

In the context of a research project I'm planning to develop a desktop application to operate with my DJI Mavic Pro 2 (or similar drones).

So, my question is: Is there anyway I can control the DJI drone from a desktop application without using the controller? For example, I would like to get the video stream in realtime on desktop app as well as automatically planning the mission for the drone.

Unfortunately, the Windows SDK only provides few APIs compared to the Mobile SDK.

Answer (score 1):

For most of the other heavy/potential killing drones, e.g mavic 2 pro or above. it need remote on so that you can fly.

If you really need to do so, How about tello? it is a small DJI drone that can allows you to control it. Moreover, it allows you to get video and imu feed from its API. There is plenty of open-source code for it.

Comment: I know Tello, and it is a really good tool to start from. However, I need a more sophisticated drone with a longer flight time.

Comment: for research project. you can refer to TUM ardrone like research.  The other like Upen FLV project drone (search msckf-stereo VIO). Which with custom PX4 controller, you can do fully autonomous flight. Most DJI drone hides the code inside which prevent you from changing the source code

Comment: if you talking about 400hz IMU, 60hz global shutter camera, with LIDAR, foresure you need to build drone on ur own from begining.

Answer (score 0):

The controller is required.

Some of the older drones had a wifi option but the newer ones user controllers at the connection.

Comment: Yes, I know I need the controller but I was thinking there may be other options.

Comment: On the aircraft in question; none that I am aware of.